# fancyBox and PDFs - Changing / Editing the filename that automatically displays (Chrome vs IE issue)

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancyBox to open up PDF files and it works fine.  The display is a little different in Chrome vs IE.  The filename automatically displays on upper left for Chrome and doesn't display anything on IE.  The other options for rotate, save, download are in different places, too.

I'm concerning with the filename.  Can I change this setting?  Or even change the name of it instead of the filename?  And make it consistent for IE, too?

Example from fancyBox page is great.  They are referencing this PDF.
https://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf
Chrome displays 'pdf-sample.pdf' on upper left, but IE doesn't display it at all.

Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of another PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUubH.jpg) - Automatically added filename to upper left side in Chrome, but doesn't display for IE.  Any ideas on how I can edit this across all browsers?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Where is the code you are using and what do you want to change of it?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the PDF.  Hope this helps, thanks!